# How can I write a python program for creating iterative clusters for k-means algorithm?

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.spatial import distance
from pandas import DataFrame
a = [2,2,8,5,7,6,1,4]
b = [10,5,4,8,5,4,2,9]
list1=[]
list2=[]
cluster1=[]
cluster2=[]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': a, 'Column 2': b})
print(df1)
x1=int(input("Enter seed point X1: "))
y1=int(input("Enter seed point Y1: "))
x2=int(input("Enter seed point X2: "))
y2=int(input("Enter seed point Y2: "))
#calculate Distance
for i,j in zip(a,b):
        c1=round(math.sqrt(math.pow((x1 - i), 2) + math.pow((y1 - j), 2)),2)
        c2=round(math.sqrt(math.pow((x2 - i), 2) + math.pow((y2 - j), 2)),2)
        list1.append(c1)
        list2.append(c2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Distance 1': list1, 'Distance 2': list2})
print(df2)
for p,q in zip(a,b):
      for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
            if(i<j):
                    cluster1.append((p,q))
print(cluster1)
```

The clusters are not created properly. Only (2,10) should be in cluster 1, the rest in Cluster 2. Similarly, this process should repeat many times until the mean of seed points becomes the same.
Finally, the answer should be data sets that are clustered. I've referred to many online codes showing visualized clusters, but I need a simple printed on screen format results.

[image]

Comment: Add some spaces in your code. It is hard to read without proper formatting

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, I'm still a beginner. I'll improve it as per what you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your logic in the second for loop is off. Is this what you are trying to get:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.spatial import distance
from pandas import DataFrame

a = [2, 2, 8, 5, 7, 6, 1, 4]
b = [10, 5, 4, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9]
list1 = []
list2 = []
cluster1 = []
cluster2 = []
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1': a, 'Column 2': b})
print(df1)
x1 = int(input("Enter seed point X1: "))
y1 = int(input("Enter seed point Y1: "))
x2 = int(input("Enter seed point X2: "))
y2 = int(input("Enter seed point Y2: "))
# calculate Distance
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    c1 = round(math.sqrt(math.pow((x1 - i), 2) + math.pow((y1 - j), 2)), 2)
    c2 = round(math.sqrt(math.pow((x2 - i), 2) + math.pow((y2 - j), 2)), 2)
    list1.append((c1, (i, j)))
    list2.append((c2, (i, j)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Distance 1': list1, 'Distance 2': list2})
print(df2)
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    d0, d1 = i[0], j[0]
    if d0 < d1:
        cluster1.append(i[1])
    else:
        cluster2.append(i[1])
print(cluster1)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [i[0] for i in cluster1]
y1 = [i[1] for i in cluster1]
plt.scatter(x1, y1)
x2 = [i[0] for i in cluster2]
y2 = [i[1] for i in cluster2]
plt.scatter(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

If so, this may not be the most elegant fix.

EDIT0: I have included code for creating a primitive scatter plot.

EDIT1: Below is the code for the follow up question mentioned in the comments. This is for k = 2.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

a = [2, 2, 8, 5, 7, 6, 1, 4]
b = [10, 5, 4, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9]

x1 = int(input("Enter seed point X1: "))
y1 = int(input("Enter seed point Y1: "))
x2 = int(input("Enter seed point X2: "))
y2 = int(input("Enter seed point Y2: "))

curr_means = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]
prev_means = []
while prev_means != curr_means:
    prev_means = curr_means
    x1 = curr_means[0][0]
    y1 = curr_means[0][1]
    x2 = curr_means[1][0]
    y2 = curr_means[1][1]
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    cluster1 = set()
    cluster2 = set()
    for i, j in zip(a, b):
        c1 = round(math.sqrt(math.pow((x1 - i), 2) + math.pow((y1 - j), 2)), 2)
        c2 = round(math.sqrt(math.pow((x2 - i), 2) + math.pow((y2 - j), 2)), 2)
        list1.append((c1, (i, j)))
        list2.append((c2, (i, j)))

    for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
        d0, d1 = i[0], j[0]
        if d0 < d1:
            cluster1.add(i[1])
        else:
            cluster2.add(i[1])
    print("c1: ", cluster1)
    print("c2: ", cluster2)

    cluster1_mean_x = sum(x[0] for x in cluster1) / len(cluster1)
    cluster1_mean_y = sum(x[1] for x in cluster1) / len(cluster1)
    cluster2_mean_x = sum(x[0] for x in cluster2) / len(cluster2)
    cluster2_mean_y = sum(x[1] for x in cluster2) / len(cluster2)
    curr_means = [(cluster1_mean_x, cluster1_mean_y), (cluster2_mean_x, cluster2_mean_y)]
    print('-----------------------------')

print(cluster1)
print(cluster2)

x1 = [i[0] for i in cluster1]
y1 = [i[1] for i in cluster1]
plt.scatter(x1, y1)
x2 = [i[0] for i in cluster2]
y2 = [i[1] for i in cluster2]
plt.scatter(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

As mentioned above,this code is not efficient and is no longer clean. For questions regarding working code (such as how to make code more efficient, clean, readable) try using stack exchange code review.

Comment: Could you explain how the second for loop works? i.e. i[0]? because list1 has two entities, distances and points. Also thanks, my cluster1 prints the correct output now. But how to make it "iterative", as in- Now it will calculate the mean of all data points present in clusters and taking them as x'1,y'1,x'2,y'2, repeat the whole process again until the means of two iteration comes same and the display final cluster. Eg: In iteration 2, (2,10) and (4,9) are in cluster1 and rest in cluster2.

Comment: list1 and list2, now not only contain the distances from the data points to the seed points, but also the points themselves. So that list1[i] = ( distance_of_pt_i_to_seed1, (a[i], b[i]) ). In other words list[i][0] is the distance and list[i][1] is the data point itself. The second for loop's job is, for each data point, to check which seed point is closest. Upon figuring out which is closer, get the data point (list1[i][1]) and stick it in the respective cluster. Technically speaking, you could have only saved the data point to a single list rather than both.

Comment: Answer revised to include @minsuga follow up question.

Comment: oh okay, now I get it. Thx @Perplexabot. Yes i should have saved the data points into a single list. I'll do it.